# simplify this @foreach/if in blade and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am fairly new to laravel (L5 specifically) and I am making my own version of a todo app rather than following one of the tutorials out there. I've learned quite a bit so far but the way I have this piece of code currently laid out in my blade template makes me think their might be a simpler way of doing this.

My `TodosController@index` fn is

```
public function index()
{
    $todos = Todo::get();
    return view('todos', compact('todos'));
}
```

`App\Todo` extends an `Eloquent` model which makes data handling very easy!

My route is:

```
Route::bind('todos', function($slug)
{
    return App\Todo::whereSlug($slug)->first();
});
```

So my page simply displays an unorded list of "todos". I want to have two separate lists. One that is for completed todos and one for incomplete. My blade template looks like this so far and looks a bit messy. Also I am looping over the results twice which is where I think I can improve on.

```
<h3>Incomplete</h3>
<ul>
    @foreach ($todos as $todo)
        @if ($todo->completed == 'No')
            <li>
                <a href="{{ route('todos.show', [$todo->slug]) }}">{{ $todo->title }}</a>
            </li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</ul>

<h3>Complete</h3>
<ul>
    @foreach ($todos as $todo)
        @if ($todo->completed == 'Yes')
            <li>
                <a href="{{ route('todos.show', [$todo->slug]) }}">{{ $todo->title }}</a>
            </li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Any suggestions to simplify that blade template?

Comment: Since you're having 2 different headings, at first glance I don't believe there is much that can be done to avoid having to iterate twice. You can try filter the result set in your controller and assign 2 variables - one with those that are completed, and one with those that are not. You can also try writing a simple macro, but I don't believe it would be efficient enough. I will edit my comment if I come up with something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DRY your code out. You could streamline it by moving the actual item mark-up to a partial template since it’s repeated in both the complete and incomplete lists:

```
<h3>Incomplete</h3>
<ul>
    @foreach ($todos as $todo)
        @if ($todo->completed == 'No')
            @include('partials.items.todo')
        @endif
    @endforeach
</ul>

<h3>Complete</h3>
<ul>
    @foreach ($todos as $todo)
        @if ($todo->completed == 'Yes')
            @include('partials.items.todo')
        @endif
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

And `partials.items.todo` would look like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ route('todos.show', [$todo->slug]) }}">{{ $todo->title }}</a>
</li>
```

I would also re-factor your loops. Instead of looping over the same list twice, you could split them in your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $todos = Todo::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->get();

    $complete = $todos->filter(function ($item) {
        return $item->completed = 'Yes';
    });

    $incomplete = $todos->filter(function ($item) {
        return $item->completed = 'No';
    });

    return view('todos', compact('complete', 'incomplete'));
}
```

Looking at your `Todo` model, I’d also make your `completed` column in the database a boolean field instead of a column containing “Yes” or “No” strings. You could then cast that column value to a proper boolean (since MySQL doesn’t have a native boolean field type):

```
class Todo extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'completed' => 'boolean',
    ];

    public function isComplete()
    {
        return $this->completed;
    }
}
```

And then re-factor your controller action to use this instead:

```
public function index()
{
    $todos = Todo::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->get();

    $complete = $todos->filter(function ($item) {
        return $item->isComplete() === true;
    });

    $incomplete = $todos->filter(function ($item) {
        return $item->isComplete() === false;
    });

    return view('todos', compact('complete', 'incomplete'));
}
```

You could even move those collection filters to a custom `TodoCollection` class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection as EloquentCollection;

class TodoCollection extends EloquentCollection
{
    public function complete()
    {
        return $this->filter(function ($item) {
            return $item->isComplete() === true;
        });
    }

    public function incomplete()
    {
        return $this->filter(function ($item) {
            return $item->isComplete() === false;
        });
    }
}
```

Sorry for the lengthy reply, but should give you food for though on how to re-factor your code.

Comment: Great answer.  This is exactly how you should handle this situation, given that there will be more logic/html inside the if block in your view.  If your just lising a single todo, this might be overkill but still best practice in my opinion.

Comment: Awesome, man thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. What you are doing in the index fn is what I was looking for. I will take your suggestion and change that field to a boolean rather than string.

Answer (score 2):

Only a bit simplified but...

You can try in your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $completed = Todo::where('completed','Yes')->get();
    $incompleted = Todo::where('completed','No')->get();
    return view('todos', compact('completed', 'incompleted'));
}
```

in Your template:

```
<h3>Incomplete</h3>
<ul>
    @foreach ($incompleted as $todo)
            <li>
                <a href="{{ route('todos.show', [$todo->slug]) }}">{{ $todo->title }}</a>
            </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

<h3>Complete</h3>
<ul>
    @foreach ($completed as $todo)
            <li>
                <a href="{{ route('todos.show', [$todo->slug]) }}">{{ $todo->title }}</a>
            </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Another approach using a subtemplate like this:

```
    //_list_todos.blade.php

    @foreach ($todos as $todo)
            <li>
                <a href="{{ route('todos.show', [$todo->slug]) }}">{{ $todo->title }}</a>
            </li>
    @endforeach
```

And your main template like this:

```
<h3>Incomplete</h3>
<ul>
     @include('_list_todos',['todos'=>$incompleted] )
</ul>

<h3>Complete</h3>
<ul>
     @include('_list_todos',['todos'=>$completed] )
</ul>
```

The advantege to use a subtemplate like the last one is you can reuse the code, and simplify your main templates.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do like this approach as well.